# Pass Authentication Token to Service

Tags: json, authentication, service, liferay

I have used lifeary service builder to build my services. some of my services require that the user is authenticated before he can use them.

how can i generate an auth token and send it in the header or in the URL?

I have tried username@host.com:password@http://localhost:8080/PortletName-portlet/api/jsonws/?serviceClassName=com.service.NameServiceUtil&serviceMethodName=getMyNames&serviceParameters=[userid]&userid=1

and it did not work!

I have made sure i have added the below  line in my portal-ext.properties and restarted the server.

```
json.service.auth.token.enabled=true
```

What more should i do to be able to pass Auth Token? is there a better method that i can use?

Comment: I think that AuthToken concept in Liferay is rather for CSRF issues. Depending on your portal setup, you can try using DIGEST or BASIC authentication for your requests.

Answer (score 2):

You actually want to use AuthVerifier. This is the best way how to access the Liferay API and be authenticated. It similar to the autologin concept.

Have a look at https://dev.liferay.com/es/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/authentication-verifiers and check out the `PortalSessionAuthVerifier` class in the source code.

The concept is quite simple. Read the request object and determine who the user is. Perform your custom authentication and return the auth result with the user identification.